# Can Shift-JIS contain zeros?

Tags: c, shift-jis

I am having to store sequences of Japanese names written in the Shift-JIS format that are scooped from the internet. I am thinking for storing them in character arrays and writing them to a file with something like:

```
fprintf(fp,"The name is [%s]\n",string_array);
```

My only concern is that if Shift-JIS characters may include '\0' then this will obviously break... but I'm not sure if Shift-JIS ever does. Unfortunately it seems Shift-JIS is such an arcane system that I can barely comprehend the definitions of the system I've found online with enough confidence to answer the question myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at Wikipedia's [Shift-JIS byte map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS#Shift_JIS_byte_map), the byte values 0x00-0x3F are not used as second bytes (and nor are 0x7F or 0xFD-0xFF), so you're fine interpreting `'\0'` as a null terminator.